# How can I read the rotational bands of nuclei from nuclear data sheets?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Recently I have been reading about collective excitations in nuclei and how in deformed nuclei rotational bands are formed due to an electric quadrupole moment.

Given this I was wondering how I can find the split energy levels and occupation numbers of the rotational bands in these deformed nuclei?

I have seen it suggested that Bohr and Mottelson Volume 2 has the information available but I cannot seem to find it.